# php preg_replace not putting dash back in?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

So, I'm doing some manipulation on lat/long pairs, and I need to turn this:

```
39.1889375383777,-94.48019109594397
```

into:

```
39.1889375383777 -94.48019109594397
```

I can't use str_replace, unless I want to have an array of 10 search and 10 replace strings, so I was hoping to use preg_replace:

```
$query1 = preg_replace( "/([0-9-]),([0-9-])/", "\1 \2", $query );
```

The problem is that the "-" gets lost:

```
39.1889375383777 94.48019109594397
```

Note, that I have a string containing a list of these, trying to do all at once:

[[39.1889375383777,-94.48019109594397],[39.18425796890108,-94.28288005131176],[39.41972019529712,-94.19956344733345],[39.41412315915102,-94.41932608390658],[39.34785744845041,-94.4893603307242],[39.1889375383777,-94.48019109594397]]

I managed to make this work with preg_replace_callback:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback( "/([0-9-]),([0-9-])/", 
               function ($matches) {return $matches[1] . " " . $matches[2];},
               $query
               );
```

But still not sure why the simpler preg_match didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that `"\1 \2"` define a `"\x1\x20\x2"` string, where the first character is a SOH char and the third one is STX char (see the [ASCII table](https://ascii.cl/)). To define backreferences, you need to use a literal backslash, `"\\"`, or, better, use `$n` notation, and better inside a single-quoted string literal.

You can also use a solution without backreferences:

```php
preg_replace('~(?<=\d),(?=-?\d)~', ' ', $str)
```

Details:

- `(?<=\d)` - a location that is immediately preceded with a digit
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=-?\d)` -  a location that is immediately followed with an optional `-` and a digit.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/6812J):

```php
$str = '[[39.1889375383777,-94.48019109594397],[39.18425796890108,-94.28288005131176],[39.41972019529712,-94.19956344733345],[39.41412315915102,-94.41932608390658],[39.34785744845041,-94.4893603307242],[39.1889375383777,-94.48019109594397]]';
echo preg_replace('~(?<=\d),(?=-?\d)~', ' ', $str);
// => [[39.1889375383777 -94.48019109594397],[39.18425796890108 -94.28288005131176],[39.41972019529712 -94.19956344733345],[39.41412315915102 -94.41932608390658],[39.34785744845041 -94.4893603307242],[39.1889375383777 -94.48019109594397]]
```